# Using PDFSmartCopy in itext sharp to reduce pdf size

Tags: itext

I've used some of the example code from itext to reduce the size of a pdf as follows:

```
Sub compresspdf(oldfile, newfile)

    Dim streamOut As New FileStream(newfile, FileMode.Create)
    Dim newDoc As Document = New Document(PageSize.A4)
    Dim pdfCopy As PdfSmartCopy = New PdfSmartCopy(newDoc, streamOut)
    pdfCopy.SetMergeFields()
    newDoc.Open()
    Dim pdfTemplate As String = oldfile
    Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader(pdfTemplate)
    pdfCopy.AddDocument(pdfReader)
    pdfCopy.Close()
    pdfReader.Close()

End Sub
```

This works well for pdfs up to a certain size, but I get memory problems when I try to use it on too large a pdf.

Is there a way to achieve the compression without holding the whole pdf in memory? - presumably going through the file page-by-page defeats the object of using smartcopy?

Comment: I should add that I understand PDFSmartCopy does trade using more memory to get the file size down. I could split the file up into separate files and run the compression on those individually, if there's no better way?

Comment: Could you add your PDF, so that one could test it agaisnt several size-reduction approaches and see whether they fit?

Comment: Anyway, the classes you mention belong to iText5 which is end of life and no longer maintained (with an exception of considerable security fixes). For iText7 (the recent verion of iText) there is a brand new pdfOptimizer plugin responsible for document's size optimization: perhaps it's worth trying it: https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/compress-pdf-pdfoptimizer